# PHPMailer unable to connect ot server

Tags: php, email, tcp, phpmailer

`PHPmailer` works just fine on my localhost, but when I moved it to the production, I am getting this kind of error:

> Connection: opening to smtp.gmail.com:587, timeout=300, options=array
>   ( ) 2016-09-28 12:58:01 Connection: Failed to connect to server. Error
>   number 2. "Error notice: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to
>   smtp.gmail.com:587 (Connection timed out) 2016-09-28 12:58:01 SMTP
>   ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110)
>   2016-09-28 12:58:01 SMTP connect() failed.

I've tried both TLS and SSL, updating ports accordingly.
Also I've run a quick nmap scan, and it show that ports are open properly, so that's not an issue

```
PORT    STATE    SERVICE
25/tcp  filtered smtp
443/tcp open     https
465/tcp open     smtps
587/tcp open     submission
```

This is a snippet from my app:

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    $this->isSMTP();
    $this->SMTPAuth = true;
    $this->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $this->Host = MAIL_HOST;
    $this->Username = MAIL_USERNAME;
    $this->Password = MAIL_PASSWORD;
    $this->From = 'myemail';
    $this->FromName = 'Name';
    $this->addEmbeddedImage('../public/img/message_logo.png', 'logo');
    $this->isHTML(true);
    $this->Port = 587;
    $this->Subject = "SUBJECT";
    $this->SMTPDebug = MAIL_SMTP_DEBUG;
}
```

Anyone know what to check next?

Comment: Did you [allow less secure apps to access your account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255)?

Comment: Yes, as I've said it is sending mails from my localhost with no problems

Answer (score 2):

This is a very common problem, usually caused by outbound SMTP blocking by your ISP, e.g. GoDaddy does this. What's that nmap scan of? gmail?

By the error message contents, I'd also guess you're using an old version of PHPMailer.

Diagnosing this kind of problem is covered in [the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting).

Comment: I am using this version atm `5.2.16`. I've checked with hosting provider, their answer was that they don't block any specified ports

Comment: So you can `telnet smtp.gmail.com 587` from your server and get a sensible SMTP-shaped response?

Comment: I can not check that, as I don't have SSH access :(
I have only FTP. I did check for open ports via remote scan from my localhost, and I was able to telnet to those ports as well.

Comment: There's no point in scanning/testing for outbound blocks unless you're inside the network! All you've shown is that your own machine (which isn't inside the network) doesn't have a block, which we knew already! There's also no point in scanning your server for inbound ports, as that's irrelevant to this problem. I suspect that your ISP *is* blocking - see if you can find anything in their support docs about it. e.g. GoDaddy blocks direct SMTP, but lets you use their own servers as relays.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about GMail, but with Office 365 I needed to disable the SSL-check.

```
$this -> SMTPOptions = [ 'ssl' => [ 'verify_peer' => false ] ];
```

Edit: you might want to make sure you trust the host before disabling the SSL peer verification.

Comment: That's nothing to do with connection timeouts - it's not getting as far as connecting, let alone starting a TLS session. You *might* consider doing that in response to some specific kinds of verification failure, but it's a dangerous thing to suggest if that's not the problem you're having.